# How to post raw json text in Jersey Client HTTP POST request?

Tags: java, json, jersey, http-post

I want to make an `HTTP POST` request, which requires parameters must be passed as raw JSON text, but I don't know how to do in with Jersey client.
Here is the API specs (works well in Postman Rest Client): (please look at the screenshot from my Postman, the URL, parameter in body, and 2 headers are Content-Type: application/json & Accept: application/json)
[image: Postman client]
And here is what I've tried with Jersey:

```
JsonObject parameters = new JsonObject();
parameters.addProperty("centerId", centerId);
parameters.addProperty("studentId", studentId);

if (fromDate != null) {
    parameters.addProperty("fromDate", fromDate);
}
if (toDate != null) {
    parameters.addProperty("toDate", toDate);
}

Object response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/rest").path("student/calendar")
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(parameters), String.class);
```

but nothing worked. Can anyone suggest what is the correct way to deal with Jersey in this case? Thank you.

Comment: You  are not using "raw" JSON. You are using `JsonObject`. Raw JSON is the string. If you pass the string value of `JsonObject` to `Entity.json` it should work. Otherwise you will need a Jersey provider that know how serialize `JsonObject`.

Comment: Actually in `Entity.json()` I passed `parameters.toString()` instead of `parameter`, it produced the exact JSON payload but still didn't work.

Comment: Can you paste what is the exception that your receiving?
I tried with this `.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(parameters.toString()), String.class);` and `.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(parameters.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));`
  
 Both of these worked for me. For later however, you need to accept it as Response Object and then invoke `response.readEntity(String.class)` to get the contents.

Comment: Here is my payload string:  
`String payload = "{"schoolId":1,"studentId":1,"fromDate":"1454259600000","toDate":"1456765200000"}"`. And here are results when I tried with each of them:
`client.target("<targetURI>")
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(payload, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));`
--> 400 Bad Request
`client.target("<target URI>")
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.json(payload), String.class);`
--> 400 Bad Request

Comment: Do I need to integrate Jackson to populate the JSON data? I've tried many times, with many API endpoints,but they always return 400 - Bad Request, though I applied those your suggestions.

Comment: @ĐinhHồngChâu, Have you solved this issue ? I am facing same issue.

Comment: I am not sure if it's an issue from Jersey or Jackson library (some friends also told me that). But I left it, and switched to Unirest. Works like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

Use an `InputStream` for your entity construction, it should work

```
String payload = "{\"schoolId\":1,\"studentId\":1,\"fromDate\":\"1454259600000\",\"toDate\":\"1456765200000\"}";

client.target("<targetURI>")
.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.post(Entity.entity(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(payload.getBytes()),
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
));
```

But in the end, `Entity.json(payload)` should also work.